# How can I get line numbers to appear automatically each time I call vim?

Tags: vim

How can I get line numbers to appear automatically each time I call vim?
I know ":set number" works interactively and I tried to put it in .bashrc, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Don't put the configuration in your `.bashrc`; put it in your `.vimrc`:

```
set number
```

Comment: Which if doesn't exists, it has to be created.